# Illustrator: Eyedropper copy only color, not other formatting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shortcuts, eyedropper

Can I copy only the color from another object using the eyedropper without copying other formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + `Click` to select a color. <kbd>Option</kbd> + `Click` (Mac) / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Click` (Windows) to fill a shape with the selected color:

[image]

*^Note: cursors aren't captured correctly in the gif above.*

Comment: I meant case with one selected object. So you can get color from another object with eyedropper and holded Shift button. Your way is good too, but slower.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting an object with the eyedropper to do this.

Comment: i wrote this answer when I found it. and it was my answer for my question/ what's wrong, dude?

Comment: My bad, I might have misflagged your answer. Carry on